# Importing Dirctory to a file in the same directory

Tags: python, python-import

[image]

How to import a directory to a file in the same directory ?? i  have tried it this way but **line 7** throws an error **Module Not found**.

Comment: FYI `core.py` is not in the same directory as the directory `classification_model`.

Comment: Importing from your own package is hard. I recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Answer (score 0):

your `classification_model` does not have an init file, try importing the specific file you want, like: `import classification_model.pipeline as pipeline` or something similar, alternatively you can add an `__init__.py` and add imports to whatever you want to expose, however maybe you should rethink your files hierarchy